# How to Decode a sealed trait to JSON - Circe

Tags: akka, akka-http, circe

I have the sealed trait below and its case class and I would like to transform it into JSON to give it as a response in my Akka Http app.

```
sealed trait HttpRestError {
  val statusCode: StatusCode
  val code: String
  val message: String
}

case class UnauthorizedError() extends HttpRestError {
  override val statusCode: StatusCode = Unauthorized
  override val code: String = "Unauthorized"
  override val message: String = "Unauthorized"
}
```

And the Route part

```
def login2: Route = {
  path("test") {
    pathEndOrSingleSlash {
      get {
        onComplete(authService.testUser.toRestError[UnauthorizedError]) {
          case util.Success(f) => f match {
            case Left(error) =>
              complete((error.statusCode, error))
            case Right(v) => complete(OK -> v)
          }
          case util.Failure(ex) =>
            complete(StatusCodes.InternalServerError)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that when the `Either` returns the `Left` side the response is empty, but the error code is correct. 
Any idea?

Comment: Ok. And where is an issue?

Comment: Updated! Sorry.

Comment: Is it your actual code or an adapted example? You have additional `()` in the `complete` in the `Left` case, so you're essentailly passing a `Tuple2[StatusCode, Error]` to complete. Just by looking at this code I'm not so sure which magnet it will pick in this case, but might be worth trying to go with "traditional" `complete(error.statusCode -> error)` as a first attempt, or "less traditional" `complete(error.StatusCode, error)`